# How to analyze feedback around chopper amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

The figures below illustrate my understanding of a typical chopping application. The input signal is modulated above the 1/f corner and below the amplifier bandwidth.

[image]

[image]

What if I wanted a circuit with non-flat frequency response (e.g. an integrator) and I wanted to compensate the offset of the underlying op amp with chopping? I do not think the figure below makes sense—modulating the input moves it away from the frequency range where the integrator has high gain.

[image]

If the integrator was implemented by adding feedback around an open loop amplifier, does it make sense to chop the open loop amplifier and move the input/output of the feedback network before/after the chopping modulators, as shown in the figure below?
[image]

If this approach is reasonable, how would I analyze the resulting feedback amplifier? Can I use the typical approach of plotting \$\log(\frac{1}{\beta})\$ on top of \$\log(A_{OL})\$ to see the closed loop gain and the loop gain?

Considering the equation
$$OUT = (IN-\beta\cdot OUT)\cdot \sin(\omega_{chop}t) \cdot A_{OL}(\omega_{chop})\cdot \sin(\omega_{chop}t)$$

Does chopping the open loop amplifier reduce the loop gain because \$A(\omega_{chop}) < A(0)\$?

Comment: If your chppper stabilized amp has the anti-alias and output smoothing filters you can work like there's a transfer function which is the chain of those filters, but the amp between them. Better to make simulations due the non-ideality of those filters. Have you found a good way to make the summing junction which doesn't spoil the result with a new offset? Chopping eliminates only what's caused in your gain block  Not asked, but search for scientific texts of  low drift and drift free integrators. The problem has already got some serious attention.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the chain of filters in an answer? Regarding the summing junction and taking a switched capacitor integrator as an example, are you referring to things like charge injection? I am considering sources of offset outside of the amplifier.

Comment: Seemingly you have a problem: You do not see any reasons for filtering the input and output signals. I write an answer about it when I have more time assuming anyone else don't do it earlier. Maybe it's useful to read something from a respected maker of practical components. Your theoretical multiply with ideal sinusoidal voltage -scheme is quite far from what I have seen in real devices. But even it needs the filters. Check this: https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-055.pdf

Comment: @EdHalfsunk I understand the need for an anti-alias filter at the input and anti-image filter at the output. Also, the "classic chopper" in figure 1 of that document is the circuit level version of my first figure. I am asking how to analyze feedback around a chopper amplifier. Is it the same as an amplifier without chopping?

Comment: It's not the same. The amp is far away from a block which only multiplies with a real number. You must take into the account the mentioned filters. They can cause harmful phase lag which make the circuit unstable or at least have remarkable effect to the closed loop frequency response.  You can simulate the circuit also in block level if you input the filters as transfer functions.

Comment: Not asked, but check if you can scrap the whole old days chopper amp concept by using the modern auto-zero technology opamps. They were already presented in the previous linked PDF. It's also called "chopper stabilization" because it needs repeated (clock driven) zero corrections. But the band limiting filters on the signal path are unnecessary. Opamps have special "null input" which is used by an automatic "measure offset and readjust the nulling voltage -circuit" . See this for more details: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/demystifying-auto-zero-amplifiers-part-1.html

Comment: @EdHalfsunk I think an anti-image filter is not needed if the modulating waveform is a square wave rather than a sine. \$sin^2(\omega t) \approx 1 + sin(2 \omega t)\$ but \$rect(\omega t)^2 = 1\$.

Comment: In the classic chopper amp the filters are still needed, no matter you have rectangular modulating waveform. At first, the DC offset is moved to the rectangular pulse frequency+to its harmonics in the 2nd modulator and must be removed by having a LP-filter. 2) You do not in practice have ideal rectangular pulses nor perfect modulators. There would be much unwanted noise( even without the DC offset) if the filters were omitted. Every state transition of the rectangular pulse inserts a click to the signal in a practical circuit.